# Add itemprop="name" snippet to an image's title

Tags: html, web, microdata, rich-snippets

I have a user profile image in my website and I want to tag it both as "image" and as "name" for a "person" itemtype. The name appears when the user hovers over the image, so I thought about extracting it from the "title" attribute of the image. Can that be done? and if not, what would be the proper solution for this situation?

Thanks alot,

Geva Tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The value for the itemprop of an `img` element is fixed as the resolved absolute url of the `src` attribute. There's no mechanism for overriding this.

Instead, wrap the `img` in a [`data` element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-data-element), assign the name to the `value` attribute of that, and add the `itemprop="name"` attribute to the `data` element as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm afraid I didnt fully understand what you meant, I am new to web programming so I may be a bit slow on this, can you perhaps show me a quick example of how this could be done?

assuming this is my image:
<img itemprop="image" src="http://www.fishkillrecreation.com/images/soccer%2520ball.jpg" title="a soccer"/>
and I want to create an itemprop of "name" type that will have "a soccer" value.

Thanks again, sorry the trouble...

Comment: @GevaTal. Do this: `<data itemprop="image" value="a soccer"><img src="fishkillrecreation.com/images/soccer%2520ball.jpg" title="a soccer"/></data>`